# I am wondering how to transfer the dataframe to json format

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I am wondering how to transfer the dataframe to json format.

```
name   ㅣ type     ㅣ count
'james'ㅣ 'message'ㅣ 4
'kane' ㅣ 'text'   ㅣ 3
'james'ㅣ 'text'   ㅣ 2 
'kane' ㅣ 'message'ㅣ 3
```

----------------------------result--------------------------------

dataframe to json fomat

```
data = [
          {name : 'james', 'message' : 4, 'text; : 2}, {'name' : 'kane', 'message' :3, 'text' : 3}
       ]
```

How to change dataframe to json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_json` and `collect_list` functions.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df1 = df.withColumn('json', f.struct('name', 'type', 'count')) \
  .groupBy().agg(f.collect_list('json').alias('data')) \
  .withColumn('data', f.to_json(f.struct(f.col('data')))) \
  .show(10, False)

+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|data                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"data":[{"name":"james","type":"message","count":4.0},{"name":"kane","type":"text","count":3.0},{"name":"james","type":"text","count":2.0},{"name":"kane","type":"message","count":3.0}]}|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I want grouped data and data with missing type key

Comment: Answer updated and fulfill your all condition I think :)

Comment: I changed the example. How can I fix it

Comment: I think the original purpose of the question is now differ, so please return your question to the original and post another question is better to find good answer.